# Show each role permission for each database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

Show each role permission for each database.

I found a query in an answer, but it shows only for connect(in the same row with commas)

I want to show for every privilege. If I add in the were clause they will be grouped, combined different permissions.

```
select d.datname,
       (select string_agg(u.usename, ',' order by u.usename) 
        from pg_user u 
        where has_database_privilege(u.usename, d.datname, 'CONNECT')) as allowed_users
from pg_database d
order by d.datname;
```